# elasticsearch not loading on the browser

Tags: elasticsearch, security

Configuration issue: “xpack.security.enrollment.enabled must be set to true”

help me to solve this problem

yes i did search for the code on the yml file

/etc/kibana/kibana.yml

did not find any about xpack security

after run this : sudo /usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch-create-enrollment-token -s kibana

this is the response :  “xpack.security.enrollment.enabled must be set to true”

on the browser :  kibana is not ready

all the status :  are active

Answer (score 0):

I think you should set

```
xpack.security.enrollment.enabled: true
```

in **elasticsearch.yml**. Then add these to your **kibana.yml**

```
xpack.security.enabled: true
xpack.security.enrollmentAPIKey: "<API_KEY>"
```

and **restart kibana**.

[Elasticsearch security](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/security-settings.html)

[Kibana security](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/using-kibana-with-security.html)